# Javascript Blob via Big Video

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load a blob via bigvideojs? I need to create a preloader for the video and it seems this might be the only way to build this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(), blob;

xhr.open("GET", "412858008.mp4", true);
// Set the responseType to blob
xhr.responseType = "blob";

xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
if (xhr.status === 200) {
console.log("Video retrieved");

 // Blob as response
 blob = xhr.response;

 console.log("Blob:" + blob);
 url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 console.log(url);

 BV = new $.BigVideo();
 BV.init();
 BV.show(url);


            }
        }, false);
        // Send XHR
        xhr.send();
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: the video doesnt play

Comment: I figured it out... big video looks at the file extension instead of the mine type